# JMeter does not run in windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: jmeter

I want to start using Jmeter for performance testing but I am unable to run it on my system.

When i tried to open Jmeter.bat through command line it display these errors

```
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib

        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib
\ext
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib
\junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:260)
JMeter home directory was detected as: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin>
```

I already set path of java. I am using java version 1.8.0_75.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` occurs if:

a) the jar containing the class definition is not present.

b) there exists some duplicate definition of a class.

The error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
```

means that the jar file is missing/corrupted, due to which you're getting this error message.

You can try these methods:

- Check if this class is present in     `<JMETER_HOME>/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar`
- Check if this jar file is not broken.
- try to use fresh installation of last available jmeter version
- check integrity of downloaded jmeter archive against PGP or MD5 signatures
- check that $JAVA_HOME is defined and points to JDK 1.6.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- Re-download from https://www.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/
- If above doesn't help launch `cmd` in 32-bit mode and run `jmeter.bat` from it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once - it was the JAR file and the java version which gave me this headache.
Update your java ACCORDING to the downloaded jmeter (or rather re download the jmeter itself) and you should be good to go